# Change Database connection by User - Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, aws-aurora-serverless, multi-database

I need to change my database connection by user.

Ex: I have databases for each company, for example, let's say we have two databases for Company A and Company B.
Users in Company A need to connect to the Company A database and users in Company B need to connect Company B database. How i can achieve this in Spring Boot?

There may be hundreds of Companies.

We are using the AWS Aurora serverless database.